# windows 7 remoteapp: access only necessary files to run only one program

Tags: windows-7, permissions, remote-desktop, microsoft-access, remoteapp

I like to set up a windows 7 desktop pc to be a [remoteapp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx) server to share the work on an ms access database (but not the desktop).

I set up a test user on the server, installed ms access, and did an `rdp` (remote desktop link) file which opened on another pc, the connection worked perfectly, i saw the entire desktop and everything worked. Tried out to modify the `rdp` to open only ms access - worked too.

**Allow only one program**

I tried to limit the permissions of this user to use only ms access. Opened `mmc` from the start menu, `file -> add snap-in -> added 'group policy object editor' -> browse -> users -> selected 'test'`. Double click on `administrative templates -> system -> run only specified windows applications` in the tree and entered `msaccess.exe`. Connecting as remote desktop works, and i could execute only ms access - it's ok, that's what i want. But if i trying to open only ms access by the `rdp` file, but not the desktop, then it exits without any warning or error message. So i can't set up the `rdp` to grant access to only one program but not to the desktop.

**Change permissions to files and folders**

Secondly i tried to ignore the access to all files and folders on the server expect the database what i like to share. Restored the previously modified settings to the default, and did `right click on drive c -> security -> selected test user -> deny full control`. On the database allowed `read and execute`. When i connected with remote desktop, opened ms access and tried to browse to file, the program exited with error message. It may be because the default directory where the file browser opens is not allowed to read, so the program cannot list the items. What do i need to allow to get a working ms access, but disable the reading and modifying of the files expect the shared one (but disable the deleting of it)?

I'm opened for alternative solutions. The goal is to work on an ms access database with my collaborators at the same time.

Comment: If the only reason is the Access database then you and the other users could install SQL Management Studio, and add the Access database as linked server and/or query via OpenDataSource. Management Studio is licensed cost free for personal and business use, and SQL server do not need to be installed to use it.

Comment: Also, you could try to look in Event Viewer (`eventvwr.exe`) in the Applications part if there are any logs as to why the application did not start.